# Use camera object from 3d studio max in OpenSceneGraph

Tags: c++, 3dsmax, openscenegraph

I have a scene made in 3ds max which contains camera object with name "Camera001". Scene is exported as *.ive and loaded by openscenegraph 3.0.1.

Problem: this camera object should be used by OSG view as main camera.

I can find camera node by it's name, but it's treated like a regular osg::Node. So I can only retrieve eye vector (position vector) in the terms of camera object.

How can I retreive all three: eye, center and up vectors? Or is it any way to convert osg::Node to a osg::Camera? Or a custom visitor which knows about cameras (special flags?) can be applied?

Comment: What kind of node does the camera node end up as in the .ive file?

You can convert it to .osg or .osgt to more easily see what the file is comprised of.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I've looked through *.osgt and found that Camera001 exported as osg::PositionAttitudeTransform. Even more, I've also found that any camera is represented by TWO nodes: Camera001 and Camera001.Target so now I know center vector.